# SSIS update column in Excel base on unique value

Tags: excel, ssis, dataflow

I have created a package in SSIS to update tables on a daily basis using data from an excel file.  I would like to schedule this package to run on a daily basis.  My issue is that I do not want to pull in data more than once.  I have added a column to the excel doc that based on formulas will populate with a "U" when the data has been modified.  What I would like to do is set a separate data flow to change the "U" to another Values after the first data flow runs.  What I have tried is pulling in the excel doc as a source as well as a destination and applying a Merge join to the excel doc and the SQL Database. Joining the two on a unique identifier, and then mapping another column to the output.  The data is coming into SQL server fine but my second data flow is not overwriting the excel file.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and VS 2010

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a dataflow, because I don't think you can make changes to an Excel file that you have opened as a data source.  I would use a Script Task.

Comment: I almost think you're going to want to add a worksheet called UpdatesComplete or something. Have a Multicast component on your Data Flow, just prior to your destination and then push the affected rows into the UpdatesComplete worksheet. And then modify your flagging system to incorporate that.